# Add data from one table to another when specific data form one table is selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a drop down menu on add_media.php that is populated from the "bulletin_date" field within the "bulletins" table in a MySQL database.  When a "bulletin_date" is selected, I would like the "filename" that is a part of that same record in the "bulletins" table to be placed into the "publications" table along with the rest of the data that is being submitted via the add_media.php form.

I'm uncertain how to add to the "publications" table the "filename" from the "bulletins" table that is a part of the same record as the "bulletin_date" that was selected.

I hope this makes sense...I does in my head, but hard to put in words... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Kind of need a bit more information before answering this, like, can you pre-populate the data from the bulletins table into the add_media.php form? This can be accomplished by retrieving the value on page load, and sticking it in a fashion like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $bulletinsDateVal ?>" />
```

This will make it part of the posted data from add_media.php. It will probably need parsing/changing after the post to format it correctly, and there is the possibility of a loss of precision depending on how this is implemented.

If you can't, or if you would rather not, do it that way the other way is supplying the id of the row in bulletins table in the form, much like above. You can then simply add the bulletin_date column value as part of the INSERT that you do after the page is posted like so:

```
// Code which handles the POST from the form on add_media.php
$bulletinDataSelectVal = $_POST['bulletinDataSelect'];

$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO publications(filename, other, form, data)
    VALUES( (SELECT filename FROM bulletins WHERE id = '$bulletinDataSelectVal'),
        'blah',
        'dee',
        'blah')";
```

Does that all make sense?

I see now after reading your comment, so you will probably want the latter then. Assuming your table has an unique id column, or some other way to identify it, definitely populate the dropdown with select's whose text is bulletin_date, but also set each select element's value to the ID of that row in the table like so:

```
<select name="bulletinDataSelect">
    <option value="<?php echo bulletinData["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $bulletinData["bulletin_date"]; ?>
```

You can then use that idOfBulletinData value to do the above insert which I have edited.

Comment: Yes, the drop down menu is being populated with the "bulletin_date" data from the "bulletins" table.  When the user selects the a "bulletin_date" I want the "filename" that's on the same record as the selected data to be placed into the "publications" table upon submission.  I know how to pre-populate the drop down menu, I'm just not sure how to "cross-reference" the selected "bulletin_date" with it's corresponding "filename".

Comment: Alright, I edited a bit to answer that question. I added a bit of mockup code to show you how I would do it, and modified the SQL in the middle to match it. Let me know if that doesn't help you a bit

Comment: I'm getting this error, Error: Column 'bulletinDataSelect' cannot be null.  What I'm not sure I understand is how '<option value="idOfBulletinDataRow">' is getting the ID of the record from the bulletin table.

Comment: You need to replace idOfBulletinDataRow with some php that outputs the row id. If you are looping through an array of bulletin_dates to show each option, this should relatively straight forward ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php ). Edited the answer again to be more precise